# Обрезает часть данных отправленных через POST

Tags: php, post

В чем может быть дело? Знаю что по умолчанию лимит на ограничение отправленных данных через `POST = 8M`.Посмотрел в браузере объем моим отправленных данных `Content-Length:83730`,то есть тут все в порядке.Но почему то в самом запросе я вижу какие данные передаются,а когда уже принимаю и вывожу,их нет.

```
arr[82][test1]:TEST
arr[82][test2]:55ca5fb1-37b7-4b28-8d5f-c1aae52f3ce1
arr[82][test3]:1
```

На Выходе:

```
[82] => Array
(
  [test1] => TEST
  [test2] => 55ca5fb1-37b7-4b28-8d5f-c1aae52f3ce1
)
```

Тоесть индекса `test3` уже нет.Перед этим никаких операций не произвожу,просто вывожу `POST`

Comment: пробовали отправить только значение [test3] ? можете протестировать ?

Comment: @quaresma89 Вы чем делаете `POST` запрос, например `form method poxt`, `ajax`, `CURL`?

Comment: Аяксом. Склоняюсь ближе к вот этому параметру max_input_vars 1000 у меня он смотрю за 1200 уходит

Answer (score 1):

Помогло увеличение `max_input_vars  1000 до 2000`